# How to add new actions/capabilities to an already discovered device under Alexa's Smart Home Skill in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Lambda gives me TurnOn() and TurnOff() functions pre-defined with a bulb to toggle. Now, I have added a new device, say TV. Alexa is discovering my 'TV' device but how do I implement Alexa.ChannelController Interface to change channels of my 'TV' device?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to first update the endpoint with new capability: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html#add-or-update-report